# React TypeScript: Setting State in 2 instances of the same element causes an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have two instances of the same component being rendered

```
<div><Modal title='Login'/></div>
<div><Modal title='Join'/></div>
```

Then inside the component depending on the prop I pass in, I  then set the state.

```
const Modal: React.FC<propsInterface> = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({showLogin: false});

  if (props.title == 'Login') {
    setState({...state, showLogin: false});
  } else if (props.title == 'Join')  {
    setState({...state, showLogin: true});
  }
```

Which cases the error `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.`

I suspect that I'm not rendering 2 instances but instead rendering one instance twice which causes the infinite loop, is there any way of making this work as I wrongly expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you only have one value to change, you can just use primitive value instead of an object
2. If you want to change state according to the change of props, you can use `useEffect`
3. Do not forget to pass the dependencies as the 2nd parameters of `useEffect`

=============

```
const Modal: React.FC<propsInterface> = ({title}) => {
  const [showLogin, setShowLogin] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (title === 'Login') {
      setShowLogin(false);
    } else if (title === 'Join')  {
      setShowLogin(true);
    }
   },[title, setShowLogin])

  // conditional render according to showLogin
  return <div/>
 }
```

Comment: This certainly stopped the error, inside each of the components im using `document.getElementById('logo');` and only the first one is being selected, how do i select the the one within the component ? is there somthing like ``thisComponent.getElementById('logo');``

Comment: It depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that you are using same component 2 times. Problem is that you call setState in every render. Calling setState causes rerendering. And rerendering call setState. Here comes the loop.

Comment: Could I set the default state depending on the props.title ?

Comment: Sure. It's jsut javascript so const [state, setState] = useState({showLogin: props.title === "login" ? false : true}); should work as expected